# Linking shared library absolute vs. relative path

Tags: gcc, cmake, linker, shared-libraries

I've been trying to link a shared library into my program and I want its path to be relative to my RPATH.

However, when I ran ldd, I noticed that the absolute path of the shared library was linked. Any ideas why?

**Edit:**

```
/home/projects/my_files/winter_fresh.so
libgcc_s.so.1 => /home/tomo/anaconda3/lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f0a3bf64000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f0a3bd47000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f0a3b97d000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f0a3e369000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /home/tomo/anaconda3/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f0a3b643000)
```

The issue is the first file. I don't want the library for winter_fresh to be an absolute path, since I have an RPATH that contains it.

Comment: Can you post ldd output? Libraries are search in rpath first. ldd calls linker to get program dependencies, it will always print absolute paths to libraries.

Comment: @KamilCuk Done.

Comment: Do you build the project with CMake? Otherwise, why do you use `cmake` tag?

Answer (score 12):

> The issue is the first file. I don't want the library for winter_fresh to be an absolute path

This most usually happens when you link against your library like so:

```
gcc ... /home/projects/my_files/winter_fresh.so ...
```

and your library does not have `SONAME` (you didn't use `-soname` linker option when building it).

To fix this, either add `SONAME` to `winter_fresh.so` (a good practice in general), or link against it like so:

```
gcc ... -L /home/projects/my_files -l:winter_fresh.so
```

An even better approach might be to rename `winter_fresh.so` to `libwinter_fresh.so`, and then link against it like so:

```
gcc ... -L /home/projects/my_files -lwinter_fresh
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is, you compiled your program using winter_fresh.so as source file, not by linking against it.
If you encoded the path to shared library/executable as `/home/projects/my_files/winter_fresh.so`, you can put your shared library inside RPATH directory, like this:

```
 $ mkdir some_dir
 $ mkdir -p some_dir/home/projects/my_files
 $ cp /home/projects/my_files/winter_fresh.so some_dir/home/projects/my_files
 $ RPATH=$(pwd)/some_dir ./executable
```

The linker searches for library named `/home/projects/my_files/winter_fresh.so` under RPATH.

Now a simple test:

```
// main.c
int main() {
  int external_function(void);
  return external_function();
}

// exlib.c
#include <stdio.h>
int external_function(void) {
  return printf("%s\n", __func__);
}
```

Now, let's create `bad.out` compiled with `exlib.so` shared library used as source:

```
$ gcc -shared -fPIC -o exlib.so exlib.c
$ gcc /tmp/exlib.so main.c -o bad.out
$ ldd bad.out
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd921db000)
/tmp/exlib.so (0x00007fe4470f7000)
libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007fe446d3b000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 => /usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fe4474fb000)
```

As you see the string `/tmp/exlib.so` points to the shared library. I can run the program, using RPATH to point the linker to exlib.so location. I need to create subtree `/tmp/exlib.so` inside RPATH, like this:

```
$ mkdir -p lib/tmp
$ mv exlib.so lib/tmp
$ RPATH=$(pwd)/lib ./bad.out
external_function
```

When running bad.out, linker searches for a file named `/tmp/exlib.so` inside `RPATH`.
Linux uses a convention for naming [shared libraries](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html). Now let's link against good.out:

```
$ gcc -shared -fPIC -o libexlib.so exlib.c
$ gcc -I /tmp -lexlib main.c -o good.out
$ ldd good.out 
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffcb01bf000)
libexlib.so => not found
libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007fc1230ef000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 => /usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fc1236ad000)
```

Now you see that `good.out` is linked against `libexlib.so`. gcc searched for alibrary named **lib**exlib**.so** inside /tmp directory when linking. I can run good.out by specyfing LD_LIBRARY_PATH to the path libexlib.so resides:

```
 $ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp ldd ./good.out
 external_function
```

Comment: I found out the issue is that "-soname" was missing when creating the shared library.