# Linking shared libraries with absolute paths

Tags: c, linker, shared-libraries, ld

> **EDIT2**: my question is not as interesting as it seemed initially because most aspects turn out to be specific to a "special gcc build"
> that is used in my environment (which I didn't realize so far...). I'm
> not sure of the detailed mechanism, but the high-level effect is that
> the executable is going to look for shared libraries in the current
> folder as soon as any `-L` argument is provided on the command line,
> or as soon as any linker option such as `--no-undefined` is used. That
> explains why, with the exception of test6, my results appear to be
> consistent with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` being set to `:` or `.` even though
> my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is genuinely unset.

I've always lived in the illusion that linking with `-L/some/path/ -lfoo` and linking with `/some/path/libfoo.so` was 100% the same thing (but so far I've never ever used the latter). Based on my latest experiments, it does not seem to be the case and I do not really understand the fundamental mechanisms at play.

There is some interesting information here:

[What is GCC behavior for specifying libraries with absolute paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47997060/what-is-gcc-behavior-for-specifying-libraries-with-absolute-paths)

and there

[Linking shared library absolute vs. relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50556472/linking-shared-library-absolute-vs-relative-path)

but that doesn't seem to explain fully what I'm seeing with this trivial example:

`foo.c`

```
int foo_func(int i)
{
    return i+1;
}
```

`bar.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int foo_func(int i);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    fprintf(stdout, "%d\n", foo_func(argc));
    return 0;
}
```

`Makefile`

```
clean:
    mkdir -p install
    rm -f ./install/*

########################

foo_simple: clean
    gcc foo.c -shared -fPIC -o ./install/libfoo.so

foo_soname: clean
    gcc foo.c -shared -fPIC -o ./install/libfoo.so -Wl,-soname=libfoo.so  

######################## Traditional way with lib-dirs (-L)

bar_libdir_%: %
    gcc bar.c -L`pwd`/install -lfoo -o ./install/bar

######################## Without lib-dir but absolute paths instead

bar_abspath_%: %
    gcc $(FLAGS) bar.c `pwd`/install/libfoo.so -o ./install/bar

bar_abspath_no_undefined_%: %
    gcc $(FLAGS) bar.c `pwd`/install/libfoo.so -o ./install/bar -Wl,-no-undefined

######################## sims

sim1_%: %
    cd install ; ./bar

sim2_%: %
    ./install/bar

test1:  sim1_bar_libdir_foo_simple                 # Works
test2:  sim1_bar_libdir_foo_soname                 # Works
test3:  sim2_bar_libdir_foo_simple                 # Fails - Error while loading shared libraries
test4:  sim2_bar_libdir_foo_soname                 # Fails - Error while loading shared libraries

test5:  sim1_bar_abspath_foo_simple                # Works
test6:  sim1_bar_abspath_foo_soname                # Fails - Error while loading shared libraries
test7:  sim2_bar_abspath_foo_simple                # Works
test8:  sim2_bar_abspath_foo_soname                # Fails - Error while loading shared libraries

test9:  sim1_bar_abspath_no_undefined_foo_simple   # Works
test10: sim1_bar_abspath_no_undefined_foo_soname   # Works
test11: sim2_bar_abspath_no_undefined_foo_simple   # Works
test12: sim2_bar_abspath_no_undefined_foo_soname   # Fails - Error while loading shared libraries
```

First things first: can anyone reproduce the outcomes of my 12 tests ?
**EDIT**: in my environment, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is undefined / unset.

For completeness, the makefile has an exhaustive list of combinations, with/without absolute paths, and also potentially using `soname` and/or `--no-undefined`.
All combinations are not equally interesting, but I fail to understand some critical aspects:

1. Linking with `-L/some/path/ -lfoo` and linking with `/some/path/libfoo.so` is obviously not the same, as shown by the different outcomes of (test2 and test6) or (test3 and test7)
2. Building the shared library with an explicit `soname` (as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50558440/8543838)) seem to be causing more issues than it solves, as shown by the different outcomes of (test5 and test6) or (test7 and test8)
3. Linking with `--no_undefined` does not only affect the link-time behaviour, but also affects the run-time behavior, as shown by the different outcomes of (test6 and test10)

Can someone explain the details of what's going on ?

Comment: When you use `-llib` rather than linking with an absolute path, the linker searches a set of directories when you run the program. This allows you to use the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable to customize where it searches.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "man ld.so" for the full details - short version below.

Answer assume that you have set the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH to '.' (or similar), based on the results of your tests - especially test1.

In my test, I got the same results as you have - with the exception of test5, f

When you provide the name of a share object, the link will store the provided name (libfoo.so, or /path/to/libfoo.so) into the executable.

When you attempt to run the executable, the dynamic link loader (ld.so), will attempt to locate the referenced shared library using the following rules:

- If a name start with a '/', it is assumed to be abs path name. This cover the test cases with abspath (test5, test7, test9, test11). All those case use full path to the share objects.
- If the name has '/' (but does not start with one), it is assumed to be a relative path name from the current path. You do not have any test case for that. It will be "gcc bar.c install/libfoo.so -o install/bar ; install/bar)
- If the name does not contain '/' (e.g., libfoo.so, or -lfoo or soname=libfoo.so), a search path (using LD_LIBRARY_PATH env var, and the DT_RPATH attribute that may have been set into the binary, and system provided libraries: '/lib64', '/usr/lib64', etc.). Given that there is not explicit search path, it will only use the current folder. This will work for the cases where the code is executed from the 'install' folder (test1, test2, test8, test10).

All other cases would fail. This basically cover the cases where the code uses path without a '.' (soname, -lfoo, or libfoo.so), and the program is executed from a folder that does NOT have the libfoo.so in it. test3, test4, test6, test12.

If you remove LD_LIBRARY_PATH from the environment (unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH), the search path will not include the current folder, and test cases test1, test2, test8, test10) will fail.

Summary - to work:

- Use abspath (NO soname) and run from any folder
- Without path (-lfoo, libfoo.so soname=libfoo.so), and with LD_LIBRARY_PATH to list of relative/abs path, and execute the program when current folder can locate the shared object via the path.
- Otherwise, it fails.

Comment: I probably should edit my message and indicate this important piece of information: all my results assume that LD_LIBRARY_PATH is empty. Can you reproduce my results in this case ? If not, any ideas what else might be playing a role ?

Comment: @DaveC. Note that there is a difference between unset, or set to empty string (or set to a blank “ “ string). Read the man page - it’s very specific. If SET to empty string, it implies that it will use current folder a a search path. Same for “:”..

Comment: Thanks for pointing out these subtle aspects. In my experiments, empty or unset has the same behavior. However, as you said, ":" or ".' imply that it will use the current folder as a search path.

Comment: As you noticed, with the exception of test6, all the test results that I reported are consistent with LD_LIBRARY_PATH set to "." even if my LD_LIBRARY_PATH is genuinely unset. The root cause happens to be a "special gcc build" that is used in my environment (which I didn't realize so far...). I'm not sure of the detailed mechanism, but the high-level effect is that the executable is going to look for shared libraries in the current folder as soon as *any* `-L` or any `-rpath` argument is provided on the command line (which explain the exception for test6)

Answer (score 0):

This might not be a fully satisfying answer, but I believe I have understood a few key points.

1. **Passing an absolute path to a shared library without `soname` bakes the full path into the executable.**
   See for example what you get with:
   `make test5 ; readelf -d ./install/bar | grep NEEDED`

The executable works consistently as long as the shared library remains at the very same location.
This is consistent with test5, test7, test9 and test11 working.
If the shared library moves (even together with the executable), it all falls apart.

2. **Passing an absolute path to a shared library with `soname` DOES NOT bake the path into the executable.**
   In contrast to what was observed in 1, see what you get with:
   `make test6 ; readelf -d ./install/bar | grep NEEDED`

Now, the executable will only work if the run-time linker can find the shared object, for example if the binary was linked with `-rpath` or if `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is set properly.

This is illustrated by the following 4 variants that all work:

```
make FLAGS=-Wl,-rpath='\$$ORIGIN' test6           # Works
make FLAGS=-Wl,-rpath='\$$ORIGIN' test8           # Works
(setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH ./        ; make test6)   # Works
(setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH ./install ; make test8)   # Works
```

Note that the advantage of using `$ORIGIN` is that if the shared library and the executable are moved together, everything continues working transparently.

Comment: Your points 3 and 4 look very non-standard. OS specific maybe?

Comment: Couldn't agree more.... That just doesn't make any sense.
Looking further into it, it turns out that this very odd behavior is caused by a "special gcc build" that is used in my environment (which I didn't realize so far...). When I switch to a "plain vanilla (and trusted)" gcc build, the behavior reported in points 3 & 4 is of course not observed. I'm going to delete these very confusing points, that have no relevance to a "plain vanilla gcc".